# XPATH from JAXB object

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Is there a way to get XPATH from the JAXB Object?
Yes,I googled it and found that I have to use  @XmlPath over fields.
I'm generating the POJO using xjc command.Is there a way to tell xjc that I need XPATH over my fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@XmlPath` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html is an extension in the [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of [JAXB (JSR-222)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).  Currently neither the reference or EclipseLink implementations of JAXB allow this annotation to be generated starting from an XML Schema.

Comment: Thank you Blaise.Is there a way to get XPATH of the node from object? My current project is using SAXParser,where I can get XPATH easily and the XPATH is used elsewhere in my code.To change SAX into JAXB parser I need a solution to store the XPATH from JAXB object.

Comment: @indu I need this xPath too. Did you find  a solution?